# Android Market on Pandigital Novel, without rooting?

Tags: google-play-store, pandigital-novel

[Pandigital](http://pandigital.net/) is advertising on their site, that users of their devices can now "download & enjoy Android apps" after applying a firmware update.

[image: Pandigital Site Ad]

I've applied the update to my wife's Novel, but haven't found any shortcut to the Android Market on the device since.  I tried using the Android Market website, and it doesn't seem like that will work without having the Market installed on the device.

Is there a way to get Android Market on the Novel, without rooting it?

More details of the device in question:

**Model Number** (in About screen) - PD_Novel
**Model Number** (on back of device) - PRD07T10WWH756
**FCC ID** - TLZ-NU706
**Firmware Version** - SH20_20110302_K_PD_INX7E_ENG_6410POP
**Kernel Version** - 2.6.29 fsysky@fsysky Mon Jan 24 18:22:16 UTC 2011
**Build Number** - PD_Novel 2011.03.02

Comment: do you know if you can install `.apk` files directly to the device?

Comment: @jlehenbauer - I've heard of some hacks/workarounds for that.  Is there a `.apk` file for the Market that I could use?

Answer (score 1):

From page 53 of the [user guide](http://www.pandigital.net/userfiles/file/Downloads/UG_PRD07T20WBL1OP2_v1_4_09-27-10.pdf), you need to install [the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and use ADB to load applications.  If you do this with [the Market](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/11/19/download-updated-android-market-v3-3-12/) (3.3.12) I would expect you would be able to use it normally after that.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the Pandigital Novel, did the update but it only gives you a 1.5 Android, which originally was promised to be a 1.6 Android.

Secondly, the SlideSAM 4.0 becomes SlideSAM 4.1 with the firmware update, but now crashes regularly when entering the Android Market online...

All in all, Pandigital left us hanging with no options... if you're lucky, you can hack your Pandigital and give it the Honeycomb 3.0 Android but if you're like me, (not a programmer), you wouldn't know a honeycomb if it hit you upside the head!

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to find a way to install `.apk` files directly to your Novel, there are files to install the [3.0.26 Market](http://www.redmondpie.com/android-market-3.0.26-apk-download/), or if that one isn't compatible for some reason or doesn't work well (it's the newest one), heres a link to the [2.3.6 Market](http://mobileplanet-waryam.blogspot.com/2011/04/android-market-v236-apk-application-236.html).

Comment: those links above are for PHONES ONLY NOT TABLETS! If you try to install you will receive a NON PARSING ERROR!

Comment: @bobpandigital7white I think the Market is unified now, does [3.3.12](http://www.androidpolice.com/2011/11/19/download-updated-android-market-v3-3-12/) work for you?